# locale not working properly on staging in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an application and I am using multiple locales. All are working fine into development environment but there is some problem with staging environment. Few locales raising missing translation error.

Here is my locale file:

```
en:
  js:
    funds:
      deposit: Deposit
      withdraw: Withdraw
      currency_name:
        usd: USD
        btc: BTC
        eth: ETH
        aion: AION
        ada: CARDANO
        vechain: VECHAIN
     deposit_btc:
        title: BTC Deposit
     deposit_eth:
        title: ETH Deposit
     deposit_aion:
        title: AION Deposit
     deposit_ada: 
        title: CARDANO Deposit
     deposit_vechain: 
        title: VECHAIN Deposit  
     withdraw_btc:
        title: BTC Withdraw
     withdraw_eth:
        title: ETH Withdraw
     withdraw_aion:
        title: AION Withdraw
     withdraw_ada:
        title: CARDANO Withdraw
     withdraw_vechain:
        title: VECHAIN Withdraw
```

When I run my application into staging environment then all btc, eth, ada, and vechain working fine. But the locales for aion give following error:

```
[missing "en.funds.deposit_aion.title" translation]
```

Here is my template for rendering this currency :

```
<h2 class="panel-title">{{"funds.deposit_aion.title" | t}}</h2>
<ng-include src="'/templates/funds/_deposit_coin.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'/templates/funds/_deposit_coin_history.html'"></ng-include>
```

Please help if anyone can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a separate (fallback) translation file that makes the other translations work? this error seems to suggest you shouldn't scope the translations with `js`; remove the second line.

Comment: I tried by removing js too, but the problem remains same.